eulerr venn diagram missing small intersection
I am trying to graph a proportional Venn diagram with eurlerr, however the final graph is missing the A&C intersection.
A = 9, B = 2, C = 0, "A&B" = 28, "B&C" = 4, "A&C" = 1, "A&B&C" = 25
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
I tried both in R and the web page. And using both circle and elipse. On the web page it includes the A&C unteraction at first but looses it once all interactions data is included.
This is the code:
library(eulerr)

# Create a named vector with the sizes of each subset and intersection
sizes <- c(A = 9, B = 2, C = 0, "A&B" = 28, "B&C" = 4, "A&C" = 1, "A&B&C" = 25)

# Create a proportional Venn diagram
plot(euler(sizes),
     fills = c("yellow", "skyblue", "deeppink"))

Thanks,
Paula


Using ellipse works fine for your data, we can use residuals error plots to check, it shows which overlaps are under/over-represented, 0 meaning exact:
library(gridExtra)

fit1 <- euler(sizes)
fit2 <- euler(sizes, shape = "ellipse")

grid.arrange(plot(fit1, fills = c("yellow", "skyblue", "deeppink")),
             plot(fit2, fills = c("yellow", "skyblue", "deeppink")), 
             error_plot(fit1),
             error_plot(fit2),
             nrow = 2)



sizes <- c(A = 9, B = 2, C = 0, 
           "A&B" = 28, "B&C" = 4, "A&C" = 1, 
           "A&B&C" = 25)
eusizes <- euler(sizes)
eusizes

      original fitted residuals regionError
A            9  9.045    -0.045       0.001
B            2  2.409    -0.409       0.006
C            0  0.490    -0.490       0.007
A&B         28 27.965     0.035       0.002
A&C          1  0.000     1.000       0.014
B&C          4  3.718     0.282       0.004
A&B&C       25 25.015    -0.015       0.002

diagError: 0.014 
stress:    0.001

The fit or "A&C" is zero, so you don't see it in the plot.

Elipse does work. Thank you!
